# Google App Engine - How Dos configuration works?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am reading about dos.xml for configure Java Application against DOS attack.
I did not understand how this configuration works.
I know about DOS and DDOS, but in this case it is confused for me.

- When I configure Blacks of IP or subnets, will all requests be blocked? I think that GAE should block only if it receives too many requests of the same IP
- What is the best way to prevent too many requests (evil requests ) in my login page? I can not have IP whitelist, because the app is available for any places in the world.
- What is the difference between a black IP in two.xml and block IP in App Engine firewall?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. When I configure Blacks of IP or subnets, will all requests be blocked? I think that GAE should block only if it receives too many requests of the same IP

Yes, that's how it's suppose to work: the IP address will be blocked only when AppEngine thinks they're abusing your resources (whatever that means). [See more here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dos):

> Do not use this service for security because **some requests from blacklisted users can still get through to your application**. This service is designed for **quantitative abuse prevention**, such as preventing DoS attacks, only.

Unfortunately there is no clear algorithm described how it's handling this so it's probably best not to rely on it.

> 2. What is the best way to prevent too many requests (evil requests ) in my login page? I can not have IP whitelist, because the app is available for any places in the world.

You would have to implement some kind of rate limiting (by IP addresses or by accounts being accessed) yourself. Shouldn't be very difficult by incrementing some memcache key's value on each authentication attempt and setting it to expire in N minutes (or whatever approach that works best for you).

> 3. What is the difference between a black IP in two.xml and block IP in App Engine firewall?

A couple of differences between `dos.yaml` and AppEngine Firewall that comes to mind:

- AppEngine Firewall can completely block access from a given IP address while the addresses listed in `dos.yaml` may still reach your app
- AppEngine Firewall allows up to 1,000 rules while `dos.yaml` can only handle up to a 100
- With AppEngine Firewall you can set up a whitelist (i.e. give access to your app only to, say, your company's network and no one else)

Also, judging from the wording AppEngine docs are using - it seems `dos.yaml` isn't the recommended approach so you would likely need to implement something yourself.